# What does the => operator do in the arguments of a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, assignment-operator

another clear n00b question:

In the following snippet of code (that works fine), what does the '=>' operator do?  I thought it was for creating associative arrays.  Is that going on here?

Any explanation helpful.

```
    foreach ($parent as $task_id => $todo)
       {
            echo "<li>$todo";

            if (isset($tasks[$task_id]))
            {
                make_list($tasks[$task_id]);
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It splits the key and value for that element of the array.

Example:

```
$fruitColor = array('apple'=>'red', 'banana'=>'yellow');

foreach($fruitColor as $fruit => $color){
  echo $fruit . ' = ' . $color . "<br>\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
apple = red<br>
banana = yellow<br>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any way you can provide some more detail/backup?  I'm trying to really understand what's going on.